# Why can't I pipe `pwd` to `open` on macOS?

Tags: pipe, macos

This is macOS specific, but seems too unixy to go in the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) community.

In Terminal, I can `pwd`, copy the result, and type `open` and paste the result and the folder will open in the Finder, but

```
pwd | open
```

prints the help documentation for `open`. Why doesn't piping work but pasting does?

Comment: that will only work if open expects you to type the directory name after you press enter.

Comment: Also, this should (not a mac user) work: `open .` (for the current directory)

Comment: @BharadwajRaju `open .` works and does seem the easiest. ty.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't have a Mac so I can't test it, but the solution should be something like:

```
open "`pwd`"
```

Not all programs take their input from `stdin` which would be necessary for the pipe to work.

Comment: The double quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: @tbodt:  Try it in `/var/tbodt's files`.

Comment: I would have thought bash would treat that as one argument... This is why I don't use bash.

Comment: @tbodt: How would any shell know if the space used is to separate arguments or part of an argument?

Comment: *You* didn't type the space, it came from the command's output.

Comment: @tbodt:  What if I wanted the space from the output?  I sure don't want to see your code!

Comment: @jamesdlin:  Go complain on the `bash` development project, but don't forget to also go bash all older shells and most newer shells while you're at it.  Over and out!

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm just saying that you claim it's impossible for any shell, but shells such as [fish](https://fishshell.com/) behave exactly as tbodt describes.

Comment: @jamesdlin it's completely *capable*, it just chooses not to be gratuitously incompatible.

Comment: @hobbs 1. I never said that bash should break compatibility. 2. If the bash developers felt like it, they could allow the behavior to be adjusted (on a script by script basis, even) via environment variables or the like (e.g. akin to `POSIXLY_CORRECT`). 3. "Gratuitous" means without reason, but a different behavior would *discourage common bugs*. That's hardly gratuitous.  Anyway, this is all pretty off-topic.

Answer (score 28):

The `open` utility on macOS does not read from standard input, but take its arguments from the command line.

To open the current working directory, you would have to say

```
$ open "$( pwd )"
```

or

```
$ open "$PWD"
```

or simply

```
$ open .
```

as pointed out in the comments below.

With the `-f` flag, `open` can be made to read from standard input, but only to open whatever it receives in the default text editor.

Comment: If the shell is (t)csh, you'd want `open $cwd:q` instead. And `open (pwd)` /`open $PWD` if it's `fish`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I believe the default shell on Darwin is `bash`, but it's always good to see solutions for other shells too.

Comment: For completeness, with `rc`, `es`, `akanga` shells: `open \`pwd` or `open \`{pwd}`

Comment: Or you can use the syntax- `open .` for the current working directory or the parent directory `open ..`  or up two directories `open ../..` and so forth.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Why would `$cwd:q` be preferable to `"$cwd"` in a csh-related shell?

Comment: @G-Man, compare `a=$'a\nb' csh -c 'echo $a:q'` with `a=$'a\nb' csh -c 'echo "$a"'` (and `a=$'a\\\nb' csh -c 'echo $a:q'` vs `a=$'a\\\nb' csh -c 'echo "$a:q"'`, that is you don't want the quotes).

Answer (score 10):

```
pwd | xargs open
```

`xargs` shoves its standart input into the arguments of its first argument.

Comment: That's only if the current working directory path doesn't contain blanks or newline or single quotes or double quotes or backslashes.

Comment: `pwd | xargs -d '\n' open`

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are totally correct. If you want an ***easy shorthand***, you can do [as @fd0 proposed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297729/why-cant-i-pipe-pwd-to-open-on-macos#comment523273_297737), and just use

```
open .
```

to open the current directory. The current directory is named `.` (a single dot) in Unix, the parent directory `..` (two dots).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipeline with `-f` to open the content of the previous command in a Text Editor. This just applies for text editors. For other apps you'll need to use the suggestion in the other questions.

For example:

```
ls | open -f
```

This would open your default text editor with the `ls` output content.

You can also specify the text editor to use using `-a`:

```
ls | open -a 'Atom' -f
```

This would open Atom with the `ls` output content.